# Submitting two or more forms to the same servlet iin JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I was learning JSP where i created a `login.jsp` and `register.jsp`.  Once form in registration page got submitted i am submitting all the values in `RegisterUser.java (SERVLET)` and getting via dopost later writing to DB.  Now i need to submit another form in `login.jsp` to the same servlet `RegisterUser.java (SERVLET)`.  How to create multiple `dopost` in servlet.  If created how the servlet will identify.  Please give me the explanation in detail.  Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think you are little confused about `POST` method. You can have any number of forms `POST`ing on same `servlet` without any change.

Comment: Then how the servlet will identify tht from which form do i submit.  In two forms i can have same name for txtbox rit?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look a servlet can have only one `doPost` method. Now its up-to you to figure out which form is submitted. You can have a hidden field with same name but different values in different forms and in `doPost` method you can figure out using this value.

```
String hiddenParam=request.getParameter("Parameter-Name")
if(hiddenParam.equals("value1"){
 //form 1 was posted
}else if(hiddenParam.equals("value2"){
  //form 2 was posted
}
```

In-fact  if you are using `Java 7` you can have `switch` of `String` to shorten up the code

```
switch(hiddenParam){
  case "value1":
    //form 1 was posted
    break;
  case "value2":
    //form 2 was posted
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
create a field
in login form
<input type="hidden" name="pageName" values="login"/>
in register form
<input type="hidden" name="pageName" values="register"/>

now in your servlet dopost method
check
if(request.getParameter("pageName").equals("login"))
{
// do login code here
}
if(request.getParameter("pageName").equals("register"))
{
// do register code here
}
```

Comment: +1 Thankyou for your effort. Though it works nice, I love the way Mr.SuKu posted the answer.

Comment: :) :) :) , actually its the same approach to pass a parameter with the form name , My pleasure if it helps